# get-acl in network drive group/user name instead SID

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, networking

I need to collect the security permission for each folders in a share, the result returns me the SID but i need the username (or the group name), how i can do this?

```
$FolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "Y:\" -Recurse -Force
$Output = @()
ForEach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) {
$Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=$Folder.FullName;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
$Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties            
}
}

$Output | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Access` property already maps to a code path that attempts to resolve the account identity from the SID, so if you're seeing SID strings instead of names, it might be an indication that the SID cannot be resolved by the machine.

You can still make an attempt to translate the individual SID value into an `[NTAccount]` object like this:

```
$Principal = try {
  $Access.IdentityReference.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
}
catch {
  # If the translation fails we fall back to SID
  $Access.IdentityReference
}
```

Then use `$Principal` in place of `$Access.IdentityReference` in the property dictionary.